# Specifying range style in which all the elements must be present

Tags: regex

I am practising my regex [here](http://www.regextester.com/)

I have the following string

```
nabcdf
```

and I would like to select all of it. so I wrote the following regex

```
(n[abc]) -> n followed by a , b or c
```

because of this only n and a are highlighted. Based on this I have two questions

1)Why arent b and c also highlighted ? since they are present as well ?

2)`[abc]` specify that either a or b or c is present. Is it possible to specify a range such as a->c in which all elements in a range should be present (i.e) so it ends up like `abc` ? I know regex has `[a-c]` however that means any element between a to c must be present. What I want is that all elements between a range should be present. Is there an expression for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n[abc]
```

Will capture only `n` and one of the `character class`.To capture more you need a quantifier like `*` or `+`.

So it will be

```
n[a-c]+ #will capture `n` and at least one of the character class
```

or

```
n[a-c]* #will capture `n` and `0` or more of character class
```

[See demo.](https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/10)

[or](https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/11)

If you want all of `abc` should be present you can use `lookahead`.

```
(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)n[abc]+
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/13